# How can i get past the samsung account "abnormal reset" on a samsung galaxy s6?

Tags: lock-screens, factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-s-6, accounts, frp

I done a factory reset on my samsung galaxy s6...well now I'm stuck on a page that wants the samsung account the phone was set up in due to an "abnormal reset" but I dont know that information...is there another way to get by it?

Comment: You made the mistake not to start the factory reset from the Android settings dialog. And now your device has triggered the "factory-reset-protection". When did you buy the device and from whom? If you bought it in an (online) shop the shop is responsible in such situations.

Comment: looks like similar to google FRP but from samsung. you need to enter previous bonded samsung find my mobile login